# How can I disable horizontal pop up buffers?

Tags: window-splitting

If my laptop is connected to a 4K monitor, org export dispatcher, magit other pop up buffers are placed *vertically* at the right side. If undocked these buffers are placed horizontally over the low-res laptop screen.

How can I disable horizontal pop up buffers once and forever?

I tried these to no avail in my `init.el`:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(split-height-threshold 80)
 '(split-width-threshold nil))
```

Comment: How did you add those to your init file? Those are just lists. Did you add them to `customize-set-variables`?

Comment: Just to expand on @Drew's comment: outside of `customize-set-variables` you need to use unquoted `setq`, as in `(setq split-height-threshold 80)`